# Transfer transaction

Tags: myetherwallet

I need help with the following :
I have made an EOS token transfer transaction from myetherwallet account to another account and I have been told it can be reversed 
"You would need this account to sign a transfer() transaction back to you"
Could anyone explain how this can be done?
Many thanks
L

Answer (score 1):

If you control the private key to an Ethereum address, you can send tokens (EOS in this case) owned by that address to a different address.

Then that different address owns those tokens. If you do not also control the private key to that address, then you will no longer have control of those tokens.

Simple :)